# Windows rollback driver location information

Tags: windows, installation, rollback

When we select the rollback option for device driver in windows operating system, generally system takes you back to last installed driver, but if say i have 3 4 drivers installed then how does it go to last one? i.e. it must be storing some information about the last driver somewhere in system files.which then it uses to pick the driver and rollback. i was trying to find out where is it exactly stores , anyone knows?
i tried to search but did not find any relevant info,

Comment: over past few days i am doing extensive deep jumping into setupapi's and pther msft tools to find out, at some point i was too close to getting it but due to some small lack of data could not get. i think i would break it in few day, will share tips once i do it

Comment: i saw comment from msft folks :  Downlevel there's no good way. Quoth one of our SetupDi folks: "the logic
is hardcoded into device manager and the data about the last driver is
stored in undocumented places".                                                              Source:        http://www.winvistatips.com/threads/can-i-programmatically-roll-back-a-driver.189010/